# .NET Field Validators broken in FF10

Tags: javascript, .net, validation, firefox

I have the following page, works perfectly in IE and Chrome, but not in FF.  In FF the only fields where validation shows up are first and last names.  Then if everything is filled out correctly the submit button does nothing.

```
<script type="text/jscript">
function CheckControls(sender, args) {

    var tCell = document.getElementById('<%=tbxCell.ClientID%>');
    var dCell = document.getElementById('<%=ddlCarrier.ClientID%>');

    if (tCell.value.length == 0) {
        args.IsValid = true;
        return;
    }

    if (dCell.options[dCell.selectedIndex].value == 0) {
        args.IsValid = false;
        return;
    }

    args.IsValid = true;
    return;

}

function CheckControls2(sender, args) {

    var tCell = document.getElementById('<%=tbxCell.ClientID%>');
    var dCell = document.getElementById('<%=ddlContactType.ClientID%>');

    if (dCell.options[dCell.selectedIndex].value <= 1) {
        args.IsValid = true;
        return;
    }

    if (tCell.value.length == 0) {
        args.IsValid = false;
        return;
    }

    args.IsValid = true;
    return;

}       
</script>
<div style="padding:20px 0px 0px 75px">
    <div style="float:left">
    *First Name: <br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbxFirst" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="tbxFirst" Text="<br />*Required Field"  /><br />
    *Last Name: <br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbxLast" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="tbxLast" 
    Text="<br />*Required Field"  /><br />
    Cell: <br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbxCell" />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="tbxCell" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="<br />*Blank or 10 Digits No Spaces" ValidationExpression="^$|^\d{10}$"
            runat="server"  /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblCellTaken" CssClass="errorCol" runat="server" Visible="false">This cell number is already in use.<br /></asp:Label>
    Cell Carrier: <br />
    <asp:DropDownList id="ddlCarrier" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
            DataSourceID="CarrierDataSource" DataTextField="CarrierName" DataValueField="ID">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Select One" Value="0" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ClientValidationFunction="CheckControls" ControlToValidate="ddlCarrier"
        ErrorMessage="<br />*Cell Number Requires Carrier"  ID="cvCarrier" /><br />
    Contact Method: <br />
    <asp:DropDownList id="ddlContactType" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
            DataSourceID="ContactTypeDataSource" DataTextField="ContactTypeName" DataValueField="ID">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Select One" Value="-1" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="ddlContactType" 
        Text="<br />*Required Field" InitialValue="-1" />
    <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ClientValidationFunction="CheckControls2" ControlToValidate="ddlContactType"
        ErrorMessage="<br />*Text requires cell number" ID="cvContact" /><br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upTimes" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlTimes" runat="server">
                All Times Eastern<br />
                Notification Start Time:<br />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartHours" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="12" Value="0" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="1" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="2" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="3" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="4" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="5" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="6" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="7" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="8" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="9" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="10" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="11" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                :<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartMinutes" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="00" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="15" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="30" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="45" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartAMPM" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="AM" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="PM" />
                </asp:DropDownList><br />
                Notification Stop Time:<br />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStopHours" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="12" Value="0" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="1" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="2" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="3" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="4" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="5" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="6" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="7" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="8" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="9" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="10" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="11" Selected="True" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                :<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStopMinutes" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="00" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="15" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="30" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="45" Selected="True" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStopAMPM" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="AM" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="PM" Selected="true" />
                </asp:DropDownList><br />
            </asp:Panel>
        No Start/Stop Time:<br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxNoTime" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
            oncheckedchanged="cbxNoTime_CheckedChanged" /><br />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    *Maximum Simultanious<br />Notifications:<br />
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlNumNotifications" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Pick One</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Unlimited</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="ddlNumNotifications" 
        Text="<br />*Required Field"  InitialValue="-1" /><br />
    </div>
    <div style="width:50px;float:left">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="float:left ">        
        *Email: <br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbxEmail" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="tbxEmail" 
                Text="<br />*Required Field"  />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexEmailValid" runat="server" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
                ControlToValidate="tbxEmail" ErrorMessage="<br />*Invalid Email Format"  Display="Dynamic" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblEmailInUse" CssClass="errorCol" runat="server" Visible="false"><br />This email is already in use.</asp:Label>
        <br />
            *Confirm Email: <br />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbxConfirmEmail" /><br />
            <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" Enabled="true" ErrorMessage="*Emails Don't Match<br />" ControlToValidate="tbxConfirmEmail"
                ControlToCompare="tbxEmail"  ID="cvEmails" CultureInvariantValues="true" Display="Dynamic" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvConfirmEmail" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="tbxConfirmEmail" 
                Text="*Required Field<br />"  Enabled="false" />
                Password: <br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbxNew" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="20" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<br />*Required Field" 
                 ControlToValidate="tbxNew" Display="Dynamic" />
            <asp:PasswordStrength ID="PasswordStrength1" runat="server" TargetControlID="tbxNew"
                MinimumLowerCaseCharacters="1" MinimumNumericCharacters="1" MinimumUpperCaseCharacters="1" 
                PreferredPasswordLength="8" StrengthIndicatorType="Text" RequiresUpperAndLowerCaseCharacters="true"
                DisplayPosition="RightSide" HelpStatusLabelID="lblPassHelper" TextStrengthDescriptions="Weak;Average;Strong;Excellent"
                TextStrengthDescriptionStyles="strenWeak;strenAverage;strenStrong;strenExcellent"  /> <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="lblPassHelper" TabIndex="-1" ReadOnly="true" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="invisibleBox" runat="server" /><br />
        Confirm Password: <br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbxConfirm" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="20" />
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="tbxConfirm" ControlToValidate="tbxNew" 
                Operator="Equal" Text="<br />*Passwords Must Match"  /><br />
        <asp:LinkButton Text="Create Account" ID="lbCreateAccount" runat="server" 
                CssClass="darkLink" CausesValidation="true"  
                onclick="lbSubmitUser_Click" /><br />
        <asp:Label id="lblUpdatePassStatus" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="CarrierDataSource" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="DataLayer.FantasyDataContext" 
    Select="new (ID, CarrierName)" TableName="CellCarriers">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="ContactTypeDataSource" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="DataLayer.FantasyDataContext" 
    Select="new (ID, ContactTypeName)" TableName="ContactTypes">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ValidatorHookupControlID('<%= tbxCell.ClientID %>',
     document.getElementById('<%= cvCarrier.ClientID %>'));
    ValidatorHookupControlID('<%= tbxCell.ClientID %>',
     document.getElementById('<%= cvContact.ClientID %>'));
</script>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console (or Firebug)?

Comment: Ahh, I see this: CheckControls is not defined

But I declared it at the top, is there something wrong in my declaration?

Comment: Script type needs to be javascript, not jscript.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure javascript is enabled in FF and that there are no javascript errors.

one error:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
```

Comment: Ahh, I see this: CheckControls is not defined

But I declared it at the top, is there something wrong in my declaration?

Comment: Script type needs to be javascript, not jscript.  Thanks!

Comment: np, don't forget to +1 and select answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the "type" attribute in your `<script>` tag.  Fix it or take it out completely.

```
<script>
```

or

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
```